# Loop multiple post types and posts foreach of them

Tags: php, wordpress

**What i want to make:**

I want to make a navigation menu where every dropdownbar is its own post type.

1. Movie

   - movie1
   - movie2
2. Book

   - book1
   - book2
3. Game

   - game1
   - game2

---

**What i've made so far:**

I'm not the best at php yet, but i tried to work something out:

```
echo "<ul class="menu">";

$post_type = get_post_types( array('Movie', 'Book', 'Game') );

foreach( $post_type as $type ) {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $type
    );

    echo "<li>".$type."<ul class="dropdown">";

    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    if( $posts ) {

        foreach( $posts as $post ) {

            echo "<li>".get_the_title( $post->ID, 'title' )."</li>";

        }
    echo "</ul></li>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

**Question:**

Is there a smarter way to make the dropdownmenu? or what can i do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that approach, except that you shouldn't use `get_post_types()` - just an array of the post type names will do.

As it stands at the moment, `'post_type' => $type` will pass an array to post_type, when it should be a string.

Also, `echo "<li>".$type."<ul class="dropdown">";` should be inside your `if( $posts ) {` before the foreach.

Comment: Thank you so much, makes perfect sense! But what should i do instead with my $type and 'post_type' => ?

Comment: Try changing just the 2nd line - `$post_type = array('movie', 'book', 'game' );`